# CV using curve and other languages besides English

Tags: overleaf, curve-class

I am typing my CV in overleaf using curve document class. I have my papers in Hindi, Sanskrit and Assamese languages. I wish to to include them under Publication. How to do it in curve document class?

I used following in overleaf, but it is giving errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,english]{curve}

% for Hindi fonts
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\setmainfont{Lohit Devanagari}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\devanagarifont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\devanagarifont}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\devanagarifont}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\devanagarifont}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\itshape}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please make your code compile for us? You can use these steps as a guide to add only what's really missing: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you